# Buffers used by WINDOW SORT operation

Tags: oracle

I have a query with the following execution plan:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name                       | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |                            |      1 |        |  21741 |00:00:11.38 |     150K|   1088 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                            |                            |  46072 |      1 |  46072 |00:00:02.92 |     138K|    241 |       |       |          |
|   2 |   FIRST ROW                                |                            |  46072 |      1 |   3761 |00:00:02.83 |     138K|    241 |       |       |          |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)              | VERP_VIG_VEHICLE_STAGES_N2 |  46072 |      1 |   3761 |00:00:02.79 |     138K|    241 |       |       |          |
|*  4 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                     |                            |      1 |  37010 |  21741 |00:00:11.38 |     150K|   1088 |  3272K|  1218K| 3302K (0)|
|   5 |   VIEW                                     |                            |      1 |   7402 |  23548 |00:00:11.17 |     147K|   1088 |       |       |          |
|   6 |    WINDOW SORT                             |                            |      1 |   7402 |  23548 |00:00:10.82 |   79621 |   1088 |  4801K|   915K| 4267K (0)|
|*  7 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                  |                            |      1 |   7402 |  23548 |00:00:07.84 |    8837 |    847 |  1599K|  1599K|  996K (0)|
|   8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | VERP_OTM_PS_CONTROL_TABLE  |      1 |      5 |      5 |00:00:00.01 |      39 |      0 |       |       |          |
|*  9 |      FILTER                                |                            |      1 |        |  23548 |00:00:07.80 |    8798 |    847 |       |       |          |
|* 10 |       HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER                |                            |      1 |   7402 |  71904 |00:00:07.76 |    8798 |    847 |  1421K|  1421K| 1756K (0)|
|  11 |        VIEW                                |                            |      1 |   4534 |   4554 |00:00:00.01 |      27 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 12 |         HASH JOIN                          |                            |      1 |   4534 |   4554 |00:00:00.01 |      27 |      0 |  1888K|  1888K| 1596K (0)|
|  13 |          INDEX FULL SCAN                   | VERP_VPS_SUPPLY_VVP_N1     |      1 |     27 |     27 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |      0 |       |       |          |
|  14 |          INDEX FULL SCAN                   | VERP_VPS_SUPPLY_VVVP_N1    |      1 |   4534 |   4554 |00:00:00.01 |      26 |      0 |       |       |          |
|* 15 |        HASH JOIN                           |                            |      1 |  37010 |  71904 |00:00:07.67 |    8771 |    847 |  1245K|  1245K| 1722K (0)|
|  16 |         SORT UNIQUE                        |                            |      1 |  37010 |   1586 |00:00:00.05 |    3279 |      0 |   124K|   124K|  110K (0)|
|  17 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL                 | VERP_OTM_STAGED_VONS       |      1 |  37010 |  21741 |00:00:00.02 |    3279 |      0 |       |       |          |
|  18 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| VERP_VIG_VEHICLES          |      1 |    246K|  36104 |00:00:07.53 |    5492 |    847 |       |       |          |
|* 19 |          INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | VERP_VIG_VEHICLES_N22      |      1 |    246K|  36104 |00:00:07.38 |     891 |    838 |       |       |          |
|  20 |   VIEW                                     |                            |      1 |  37010 |  21741 |00:00:00.12 |    3279 |      0 |       |       |          |
|  21 |    WINDOW SORT                             |                            |      1 |  37010 |  21741 |00:00:00.11 |    3279 |      0 |  1612K|   624K| 1432K (0)|
|  22 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | VERP_OTM_STAGED_VONS       |      1 |  37010 |  21741 |00:00:00.03 |    3279 |      0 |       |       |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("S"."VIN"=:B1 AND "S"."STAGE_CODE"='YARD_RECEIPT')
   4 - access("VINS"."VIN_SEQUENCE"="VONS"."VON_SEQUENCE" AND "VINS"."PORT_CODE"="VONS"."PORT_CODE" AND "VINS"."INT_COLOR_CODE"="VONS"."INT_COLOR_CODE" AND 
              "VINS"."EXT_COLOR_CODE"="VONS"."EXT_COLOR_CODE" AND "VINS"."SPEC_CODE"="VONS"."SPEC_CODE" AND "VINS"."OPTION_CODE"="VONS"."OPTION_CODE" AND 
              "VINS"."MODEL_CODE"="VONS"."MODEL_CODE")
   7 - access("C"."PORT"=CASE "VVV"."VEHICLE_SOURCE" WHEN 'SIA' THEN '020' ELSE "from$_subquery$_006"."PORT_CODE" END )
   9 - filter("VPT"."PORT"=CASE "VVV"."VEHICLE_SOURCE" WHEN 'SIA' THEN '020' ELSE "from$_subquery$_006"."PORT_CODE" END )
  10 - access("VVVP"."VESSEL_PORT_ID"="VVV"."VESSEL_PORT_ID")
  12 - access("VVP"."PORT_ID"="VVVP"."PORT_ID")
  15 - access("VVV"."SOA_MODEL_CODE"="VPT"."MODEL_CODE" AND "VVV"."SOA_OPTION_CODE"="VPT"."OPTION_CODE" AND "VVV"."SOA_SPEC_CODE"="VPT"."SPEC_CODE" AND 
              "VVV"."SOA_EXT_COLOR_CODE"="VPT"."EXT_COLOR_CODE" AND "VVV"."SOA_INT_COLOR_CODE"="VPT"."INT_COLOR_CODE")
  19 - access("VVV"."PS_STATUS"='NOT_MATCHED')
```

I am interested to know why the `WINDOW SORT` operation in step #6 is requiring so many buffer gets.  I usually don't see that sort of thing for a `WINDOW SORT` operation.  For example see the operation in step 21 of the same plan -- no additional buffer gets.

Does anyone know what these buffer gets are?  I suspect that maybe the sort operation is spilling to disk, due to its size, and the extra buffer gets are to access those temp tablespace blocks.  I'd like confirmation or alternate explanations, as appropriate.  Thanks.

#### UPDATE

To hopefully clarify: I want to know why step 6 required added buffer gets beyond what was required to get through step 7.  I.e., why it is not like the buffer gets in step 21, which did not increase the number from what was necessary to get through step 22.

Comment: This is helpful. [Unnecessary Buffer Sort Operations](http://oracle-randolf.blogspot.in/2015/01/unnecessary-buffer-sort-operations.html)

Comment: Share your statistics, if possible.

Comment: The link doesn't seem relevant.  What statistics do you mean?  I think you may have misunderstood my question.  I'll try to clarify it.

Comment: Also provide table structure and actually query used.  Window Sort is an operation that sorts the incoming rowsource by the partition columns and the order columns.